# Помогите растолковать sql запрос

Tags: php, sql, if

В коде встретил такой запрос:

```
"SELECT *, IF(parent_id, parent_id, goods_id) AS pid " .
        " FROM " . $GLOBALS['ecs']->table('cart') . " " .
        " WHERE session_id = '" . SESS_ID . "' AND rec_type = '" . CART_GENERAL_GOODS . "'" .
        " ORDER BY pid, parent_id";
```

Не понял этот участок

```
IF(parent_id, parent_id, goods_id) AS pid
```

Я так понимаю что переменной pid мы присваиваем значение этой функции

```
IF(parent_id, parent_id, goods_id)
```

но это же не функция, а оператор ветвления?

Comment: почему же. IF в mysql - это именно функция. Если parent_id не 0 и не NULL, то возвращает его, иначе goods_id

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Control_flow_functions.html

Comment: @Mike, cпасибо, с помощью гугла не удалось найти ответ. 
Я только не понял почему 2 раза передается parent_id?

Comment: @РоманМальцев потому, что первый раз это то, что проверяется на *0* или *null*, а второй - это то, какое значение должно подставляться, в случае когда `parent_id` не *null*, раз мы его проверяем, то его и подставляем..... по факту вместо второго `parent_id` можно было бы написать все что угодно и любую другую переменную, хоть `666`.... например `IF(1<2,'yes','no')` .......на `php` это выглядело бы примерно так: `$myVar = $parent_id != null ? $parent_id : goods_id;`